# Mensagem de erro através da middleware Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou tentando passar uma msg de erro através de uma middleware. Se usar $errors->all() o erro aparece, mas como usar o $errors->has('active')? Ou se teria como passar apenas essa mensagem da middleware mais facilmente? Outra dúvida é como personalizar o erro de email por exemplo?

Middleware:

```
namespace Ecommerce\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckStatus
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->active != 'yes') {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Usuário precisa de aprovação');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

View Login:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus placeholder="Email">
    </div>
        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
        @if ($errors->has('active'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('active') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Tinha passado dessa forma mas devo ter feito algo errado. Mas deu certo agora. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta passando apenas uma mensagem sem especificar o nome do erro.
tenta assim :

```
->withErrors(['active'=>'Usuário precisa de aprovação']);
```